# Release or free memory in oclMat

Tags: opencv, opencl

I have a program that uses opencv and oclMat.
When I tried to run this my PC gets slow and sometimes get freezed.
I guess there are two much memory in GPU. So, my question is how can I release the memory allocated by opencv ocl mat. I execute 4 kernels. Something like this:

I create the oclmat and call the kernel and pass the matrices to the kernel.The result is a ocl mat which is used in the following kernel. M3,M4,M8,M9,M5,M10 are matrices that hold data inside the kernel. I am not using local memory(as the target device does not support local memory). SO, I am using the above mentioned ocl mat as data holder. All the temporary calculated data inside the kernel is stored in those matrix. They work the way a local memory would have worked here.I do not need them in the next kernel. SO I want to free them. What is the process to do that?

oclmat M1,M2,M3,M4
kernel1 (M1,M2,M3,M4)
oclmat M5,M6
kernel2(M4,M5,M6)
oclmat M7,M8,M9
kernel3(M6,M7,M8,M9)
oclmat M10,M11
kernel2(M9,M10,M11)

Comment: How are you allocating the `oclMat` variables? (e.g with `new`, or just automatic variables).

Comment: Like this: ocl::oclMat tempBuffer_2;
    //tempBuffer_2.create(totalWGX*16,totalWGY*16, CV_32FC1);
    tempBuffer_2.create(image.rows,image.cols, CV_32FC1);

Comment: Have you tried using the `release()` function? The documentation (and source code) suggests that this will release the underlying OpenCL memory object: http://fossies.org/dox/opencv-2.4.9/classcv_1_1ocl_1_1oclMat.html#a2a0c869ae649fe790de272feb7989b33

Comment: I found it later. And I am using it and doing some other changes. Have not tested it properly on my arm board.

Comment: Its not working. Whenever I try with a HD video, my system (Desktop) freezes.